# GameTheory package: Convert data frame of games to Coalition Set

Tags: r, dataframe, set

I am looking to explore the `GameTheory` package from CRAN, but I would appreciate help in converting my data (in the form of a data frame of unique combinations and results) in to the required coalition object. The precursor to this I believe to be an ordered list of all coalition values (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GameTheory/vignettes/GameTheory.pdf).

My real data has n ~ 30 'players', and unique combinations = large (say 1000 unique combinations), for which I have 1 and 0 identifiers to describe the combinations. This data is sparsely populated in that I do not have data for all combinations, but will assume combinations not described have zero value. I plan to have one specific 'player' who will appear in all combinations, and act as a baseline.

By way of example this is the data frame I am starting with:

```
require(GameTheory)
games <- read.csv('C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\SampleGames.csv', header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
games

  n1 n2 n3 n4  Stakes Wins  Success_Rate
1  1  1  0  0     800   60         7.50%
2  1  0  1  0     850   45         5.29%
3  1  0  0  1  150000   10         0.01%
4  1  1  1  0     300   25         8.33%
5  1  1  0  1    1800   65         3.61%
6  1  0  1  1    1900   55         2.89%
7  1  1  1  1     700   40         5.71%
8  1  0  0  0 3000000   10      0.00333%
```

where n1 is my universal player, and in this instance, I have described all combinations.

To calculate my 'base' coalition value from player {1} alone, I am looking to perform the calculation: 0.00333% (success rate) * all stakes, i.e.
0.00333% * (800 + 850 + 150000 + 300 + 1800 + 1900 + 700 + 3000000) = 105

I'll then have zero values for {2}, {3} and {4} as they never "play" alone in this example.

To calculate my first pair coalition value, I am looking to perform the calculation:
7.5%*(800 + 300 + 1800 + 700) + 0.00333%*(850 + 150000 + 1900 + 3000000) = 375

This is calculated as players {1,2} base win rate (7.5%) by the stakes they feature in, plus player {1} base win rate (0.00333%) by the combinations he features in that player {2} *does not* - i.e. exclusive sets.

This logic is repeated for the other unique combinations. For example row 4 would be the combination of {1,2,3} so the calculation is:
7.5%*(800+1800) + 5.29%*(850+1900) + 8.33%*(300+700) + 0.00333%*(3000000+150000) = 529  which descriptively is set {1,2} success rate% by Stakes for the combinations it appears in that {3} does not, {1,3} by where {2} does not feature, {1,2,3} by their occurrences, and the base player {1} by examples where neither {2} nor {3} occur.

My expected outcome therefore should look like this I believe:

```
c(105,0,0,0,  375,304,110,0,0,0,  529,283,246,0, 400)
```

where the first four numbers are the single player combinations {1} {2} {3} and {4}, the next six numbers are two player combinations {1,2} {1,3} {1,4} (and the null cases {2,3} {2,4} {3,4} which don't exist), then the next four are the three player combinations {1,2,3} {1,2,4} {1,3,4} and the null case {2,3,4}, and lastly the full combination set {1,2,3,4}.

I'd then feed this in to the `DefineGame` function of the package to create my coalitions object.

Appreciate any help: I have tried to be as descriptive as possible. I really don't know where to start on generating the necessary sets and set exclusions.

Comment: You know that you have to consider for n=30 in total 2^30-1 nonempty coalitions. This array needs at least 8 GB memory on a 64-bit computer system. Moreover, can you tell me what kind of solution you want to compute? For instance, the nucleolus of this package can only handle four person games, and miscalculate this solution except for those given in the manual. Exemplarily, consider $c(2,2,2,4,11,2,2,2,2,2,16,2,18,17,18)$, which has as its nucleolus $(13/3,10/3,19/3,4)$. However, this package returns only garbage. Hence, I cannot recommend to use this package in a scientific project.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. Yes - I've since realised that brute force computation is not realistic and have moved to a formulaic approach.